# How to import gitsubmodule containing golang code with go.mod and go.sum file

Tags: git, go, git-submodules

I am facing issue in importing a gitsubmodule containing golang package with go.mod and go.sum file inside the package inside main project directory. But facing issue in importing the package.

go.mod inside gitsubmodule package

```
module abc

go 1.18
```

go.mod inside main project directory

```
module def

go 1.18
```

files inside the gitsubmodule go package has imports

```
package abc

import "abc/sample"
```

file for main project package

```
package main

import "def/abc/sample"
```

the structure of my project code is like this:-

```
|── go.sum
|── go.mod
|── main.go import "def/abc"
abc
    ├── constant
    |    ├── constant.go
    ├── abc.go  ----> import "abc/constant"
    |── go.mod
    |── go.sum
```

and but import "abc/constant" giving problem for gitsubmodule saying import error when I try to run main.go file

Comment: You say "an issue", but you don't say *what* issue. What command(s) are you running? What do you expect them to produce and what do they do instead? See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution to this problem is inside the main go.mod file add the following
line

```
replace abc => ./abc
```

and do go mod tidy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).